# Cannot add collectionView outlet to UICollectionViewController in nib

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xcode7, nib

I'm trying to instantiate a `UICollectionViewController` in the following fashion:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UINib(nibName: "TestController", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)
    }
}
```

My nib is called `TestController.xib` and contains a `UICollectionViewController` containing a `UICollectionView`. When I add inside the nib an outlet `collectionView` from the `UICollectionViewController` to the `UICollectionView`, the line above throws the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
```

Probably there is a mistake in my thinking but I can't figure out why this error should happen.

Here is my nib:

[image]

### EDIT:

When I don't add any outlet in my nib, the error disappears. But then the `collectionView` inside my `UICollectionViewController` is `nil` like so:

```
public class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //unwrapping error!
        self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() 
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

### EDIT 2:

I reproduced the error in this simple xcode project: https://github.com/Damnum/ReproduceControllerBug

Comment: Can you add some code.That will help community.

Comment: You said "When I add inside the nib a segue collectionView from the UIViewController to the CollectionView..." 

That makes no sense. A `UICollectionViewController` creates and manages a collection view (and nothing else.) If your nib defines a `UICollectionViewController` then a segue does not apply. Plus segues are features of Storyboards, not nibs. Edit your question to show your code and perhaps a screen-shot of the nib layout.

Comment: if you use UICollectionViewController, the collectionView is automatically outlet, don't drag the Outlet.

Comment: because UICollectionVIewController already added UICollectionView , so there is no need to add outlet for UICOllectionView

Comment: @IyyappanRavi and Saurabh: when I don't drag the outlet, the collectionView attribute inside the UICollectionViewController is nil in viewDidLoad(). That's why I created the outlet. Or is there another way?

Comment: @DuncanC sorry it meant to be "outlet" instead of "segue". I corrected my question.

Comment: In collectionViewController use the nib file same controller, don't use separater CollectionViewCell,.

Comment: @IyyappanRavi the CollectionViewController in my nib is an instance of MyCollectionViewController (custom class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that although Interface Builder is displaying that controller as a UICollectionViewController, the internal magic link to collectionView is broken. Reasons for that include

- It was created as a different controller type, and class was renamed to UICollectionView
- It was created as a UICollectionView, but the class was edited to something else that IB recognized, then edited back
- Something edited the XML source behind your back. Version control restore whilst actively editing perhaps?
- IB crashed, got confused, or just felt cranky

But as people noted, in a correctly constructed nib collectionView absolutely will be populated at viewDidLoad time. So if it's not, I suggest dragging out a new controller instance and throwing this one away. That is almost certainly going to be quicker than trying to figure out exactly how and why the plumbing got broken on this one.

EDIT:

TIL that old school nib paradigms don’t work in Swift. Who knew? Not I, I'd only used storyboards since the dawn of Swift. How to correctly load a UICollectionView subclass as your main view without a storyboard [is on Github here](https://github.com/alexcurylo/ReproduceControllerBug) for those of you encountering the same issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to reproduce the error in an extremely simple setup: https://github.com/Damnum/ReproduceControllerBug Could you maybe have a look?

Comment: Hmmm, why you're right. collectionView is nil, although a valid one gets passed to the data source methods. That's ... strange. Been several years since I configured a collection view without a storyboard though, so no doubt there's some trick that's slipped my mind. I'll see if I can puzzle it out if I can make some time ... in the meantime, I **strongly** recommend storyboards for collection views, managing cell types and the like is much easier.

Comment: A PR is waiting for you demonstrating how to make this work in Swift.

Comment: Thanks so much for the working solution! The reason why I'm using a nib in this case is I need two collection views in one screen. I couldn't figure out a way to do that in a storyboard. Anyway, your solution will work for my use case!

Comment: How I'd do that in a storyboard is to use container views to embed separate controllers -- I'm a big fan of reducing complexity by using composition. That does take a little to get a handle on though.